# How to setup collabnet Edge subversion with Active directory domain services?

Tags: active-directory, subversion-edge

I have installed windows server 2008 and on this I had added Roll "Active Directory Domain Services". Now I have added a computer (windows 7) under this domain and which have installed collabnetEdge subversion.  Now I am trying to connect "LDAP authentication against an LDAP server" but it is giving error “The server could not bind to port ‘3343’. Check permission to use the port and that another process is not using the port.”

In Server Pc under the Domain I have created a OU named OrgUnit and under this OU  I had created an user.

Now my setting is given below:

Server Setting :
[image]

Authentication :

[image]

Now these two setting saved successfully but when I start collabnetEdge server it gives error "The server could not bind to port ‘3343’. Check permission to use the port and that another process is not using the port". I have changed port but same error occurs. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Your LDAP Settings look good, but it is impossible to know for sure.

Your problem is on the first page where you specified port 3343.  You cannot do that.  The port number you are specifying is the one you want your Apache Subversion server to use.  This has to be an unused port.  Normally you want it to be port 80 or 443 depending on whether or not you are using SSL.

Since you are going to use your AD credentials, using SSL is a good idea.  So I would check the box for Apache encryption and use port 443.

Port 3343 is the port that the SVN Edge console is using.  So it will always be in use and could not be used.

Comment: I checked the checkbox Apache encryption and use port 443.
I tried it but it is not working, it gives same error.